# DockerFile's CMD equivalent in Packer's Docker Build

Tags: docker, dockerfile, packer

I have a node application intended to run in a docker container. I'm using packer to build the image, hence without using Dockerfile. I want to start the node application by default when run the container. DockerFile has "CMD" to realize this. I couldn't find anything related to this in Packer's docs (i.e. to specify packer builder json's post processing). Googling just ended up finding plugins like this https://github.com/cornfeedhobo/packer-post-processor-docker-dockerfile (where it mention packer tends to support it)

I'm sure someone using packer for docker encountered this before. Any clues how to have DockerFile's CMD equivalent in packer's docker build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `changes`

```
{ 
  "type": "docker", 
  "image": "ubuntu",
  "commit": true,
  "changes": [
    "CMD [\"nginx\", \"-g\", \"daemon off;\"]",
    "ENTRYPOINT /var/www/start.sh"
    ]
 }
```

See [this example in the docs](https://www.packer.io/docs/builders/docker.html#basic-example-changes-to-metadata)

Comment: I had read this earlier, but thought it's applicable to starting base image before provisioning. Tried out now and it worked, thanks!